# Spark Structured Streaming shows no output on Databricks with Trigger.Once

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

> I ran this on Databricks CE in a notebook and it produces output to a
> delta table. I am using `.format("rate")` approach.
>
> ```
> val streamingQuery = aggregatesDF.writeStream
>   .format("delta")
>   .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _)
>   .outputMode("update")
>   .start()
> ```
>
> Running this, however, produces no output! It stops after one
> invocation, but the table remains empty.

Reason is?

Surely not a CE limitation? Error?

- Can this processing mode not be run in a cell?
- Volume issue?
- This brings the question to mind, can Trigger Once only be used in the Databricks environment? I am assuming I can run this as a jar under Linux.

> Could it be a bug, here goes:
>
> ```
> import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
>
> val streamingQuery = aggregatesDF.writeStream
>   .trigger(Trigger.Once())
>   .format("delta")
>   .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _)
>   .outputMode("update")
>   .start()
> ```

`.format("rate")`, could that be the issue? Which is handy for prototyping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trigger.Once` isn't limited to Databricks - it's a standard functionality of Spark Structured Streaming.  But the problem is that it requires a data source that has a history as it triggers processing of the data since last execution, and `rate` source don't have a history, always start from the beginning.  It's easy to show:

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("rate").load()
df.writeStream.trigger(once=True).option("checkpointLocation", "1.cp") \
  .outputMode("append").save("1.parquet")
spark.read.parquet("1.parquet").show()
+---------+-----+
|timestamp|value|
+---------+-----+
+---------+-----+
```

If you want to continue to use `rate` for experimenting, it's better to create an additional table that will be a buffer between `rate` and your code.  Something like this:

```py
# Create a buffer table
df = spark.readStream.format("rate").load()
df.writeStream.trigger(once=True).option("checkpointLocation", "buffer.cp") \
  .format("delta").outputMode("append").save("1.delta")

# Use buffer table
bufferDF = spark.read.stream.format("delta").load("1.delta")
aggregatesDF = bufferDF....
streamingQuery = aggregatesDF.writeStream
  .trigger(once=True)
  .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _)
  .outputMode("update")
  .start()
```

P.S. It makes no sense use `.format("delta")` together with `.foreachBatch` - the latter takes precedence.

Comment: Ok sort of figured rate would be the issue. Memory stream also an issue then?

Comment: Not sure on your last comment as it was from databricks that i dourced that code. The ps that is.

Comment: can you point to a page from which you took it? I can ask doc team to fix it

Comment: You can't stream from `memory` - there is no such source

Comment: I will look for it now, closed the window. let me search. I am pretty sure i used memory stream to simulate stream input in prototyping in the past.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-streaming.html